# C# Ionic.Zlib Decompress and Compress different

Tags: c#, byte, zlib, deflatestream

**Summary:** when doing `var x = decompress(input); var ouput = compress(x);` using the same DeflateStream and CompressionLevel the result for `input==output` equals *false*.. Why?

---

I am working on editing some Age of Empire 2 maps. I tried to copy as much logic as possible from a working [JS project](https://peterolson.github.io/AOE2-Real-Map-Creator/js/saveMap.js) but am stuck when Compressing the final Byte[] to output.

The goal is to open the aoe2scenario file and edit the *terrain* values. I am already able to generate a byte[] similar to the uncompressed 'map'. This will replace the `var map` in the `//body` part.

**The question:**
Why is the value of `byte[] compressedMapContent` at the end of saveMap Function different compared to `var compressed = buffer.Skip(79).ToArray();` at the beginning? This should be the same right?

```
using Ionic.Zlib;

namespace Image2Age {
    class MapManager {

        public void SaveMap() {
            // map.aoe2scenario file
            // Goal: decompress and extract values. Change map tiles to different terrains. Recompress as new map
            // 8 + 7*mapSizeX*mapSizeY

            // lazy load (instead of file load)
            byte[] buffer = new byte[] { 49, 46, 51, 55, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 3, 135, 169, 94, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 232, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 68, 105, 122, 122, 121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 236, 219, 189, 138, 19, 81, 24, 128, 225, 51, 155, 253, 49, 254, 182, 218, 45, 104, 161, 141, 133, 157, 90, 40, 9, 66, 74, 193, 194, 198, 194, 97, 29, 48, 133, 9, 100, 131, 120, 1, 54, 130, 197, 130, 149, 130, 151, 32, 94, 134, 94, 133, 215, 224, 21, 24, 231, 36, 25, 55, 102, 51, 103, 97, 119, 10, 179, 62, 47, 124, 60, 201, 30, 51, 159, 78, 214, 114, 66, 217, 173, 103, 95, 31, 68, 37, 73, 146, 36, 73, 210, 217, 238, 215, 100, 50, 57, 205, 100, 229, 53, 226, 220, 40, 103, 115, 254, 58, 86, 189, 175, 58, 235, 239, 79, 90, 117, 191, 194, 181, 208, 237, 118, 199, 197, 254, 248, 105, 62, 46, 70, 183, 243, 97, 113, 103, 127, 175, 24, 228, 163, 254, 176, 238, 222, 175, 186, 94, 107, 213, 181, 85, 83, 182, 212, 231, 154, 187, 122, 236, 117, 18, 103, 27, 137, 179, 197, 111, 107, 185, 212, 111, 215, 86, 226, 108, 59, 113, 182, 147, 56, 59, 151, 56, 107, 39, 206, 206, 39, 206, 46, 36, 206, 46, 38, 206, 46, 37, 206, 46, 39, 206, 174, 148, 19, 191, 195, 227, 126, 243, 223, 150, 55, 254, 230, 245, 217, 253, 55, 198, 252, 159, 35, 73, 146, 36, 73, 146, 36, 73, 146, 36, 73, 146, 36, 73, 146, 36, 73, 235, 210, 73, 159, 119, 249, 171, 172, 145, 7, 161, 254, 153, 226, 243, 58, 167, 153, 120, 79, 171, 238, 215, 236, 120, 94, 62, 52, 19, 167, 124, 210, 229, 231, 151, 31, 211, 39, 132, 222, 204, 231, 94, 8, 241, 147, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 172, 21, 237, 16, 235, 117, 103, 243, 189, 115, 56, 139, 63, 95, 239, 179, 248, 111, 188, 26, 158, 236, 21, 131, 124, 212, 31, 238, 62, 122, 209, 31, 15, 71, 187, 143, 95, 230, 131, 241, 240, 85, 184, 251, 250, 67, 231, 219, 187, 247, 157, 94, 232, 133, 208, 14, 173, 208, 154, 21, 63, 155, 149, 179, 153, 152, 121, 15, 15, 95, 206, 139, 183, 182, 126, 101, 8, 7, 229, 95, 238, 224, 207, 202, 106, 103, 252, 100, 188, 108, 106, 109, 60, 107, 98, 229, 124, 103, 181, 50, 181, 118, 163, 169, 149, 179, 157, 139, 43, 235, 214, 78, 255, 80, 35, 43, 167, 59, 151, 87, 214, 173, 109, 104, 101, 220, 185, 106, 229, 242, 218, 173, 6, 87, 150, 59, 235, 86, 46, 174, 221, 110, 114, 229, 236, 91, 74, 253, 7, 137, 107, 119, 82, 43, 143, 252, 112, 69, 159, 62, 198, 178, 163, 23, 144, 244, 127, 247, 123, 0 };
            int length = 8 + 7 * 120 * 120;

            var mapHeader = buffer.Take(79).ToArray();

            // content
            var compressed = buffer.Skip(79).ToArray();
            var uncompressedMapContent = decompress(compressed);
            int index = Array.FindIndex(uncompressedMapContent, element = >element.Equals(120));

            //header
            var header = uncompressedMapContent.Take(index).ToArray();
            //foot
            var foot = uncompressedMapContent.Skip(index + length).ToArray();

            // body

            var tempMap = uncompressedMapContent.Take(index + lenght).ToArray();
            var map = tempMap.Skip(index).ToArray();

            //combine
            byte[] newMapContent = new byte[header.Length + map.Length + foot.Length];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(header, 0, newMapContent, 0, header.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(map, 0, newMapContent, header.Length, map.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(foot, 0, newMapContent, header.Length + map.Length, foot.Length);

            //recompress as new map
            var compressedMapContent0 = compress(newMapContent, 0);
            var compressedMapContent1 = compress(newMapContent, 1);
            var compressedMapContent2 = compress(newMapContent, 2);
            var compressedMapContent3 = compress(newMapContent, 3);
            var compressedMapContent4 = compress(newMapContent, 4);
            var compressedMapContent5 = compress(newMapContent, 5);
            var compressedMapContent6 = compress(newMapContent, 6);
            var compressedMapContent7 = compress(newMapContent, 7);
            var compressedMapContent8 = compress(newMapContent, 8);
            var compressedMapContent9 = compress(newMapContent, 9);

            Console.WriteLine("Orig: " + string.Join(", ", compressed));
            Console.WriteLine("lvl0: " + string.Join(", ", compressedMapContent0));
            Console.WriteLine("lvl1: " + string.Join(", ", compressedMapContent1));
            Console.WriteLine("lvl2: " + string.Join(", ", compressedMapContent2));
            Console.WriteLine("lvl3: " + string.Join(", ", compressedMapContent3));
            Console.WriteLine("lvl4: " + string.Join(", ", compressedMapContent4));
            Console.WriteLine("lvl5: " + string.Join(", ", compressedMapContent5));
            Console.WriteLine("lvl6: " + string.Join(", ", compressedMapContent6));
            Console.WriteLine("lvl7: " + string.Join(", ", compressedMapContent7));
            Console.WriteLine("lvl8: " + string.Join(", ", compressedMapContent8));
            Console.WriteLine("lvl9: " + string.Join(", ", compressedMapContent9));

            var compressedMapContent = compress(newMapContent, 9);

            byte[] combined = new byte[mapHeader.Length + compressedMapContent.Length];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(mapHeader, 0, combined, 0, mapHeader.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(compressedMapContent, 0, combined, mapHeader.Length, compressedMapContent.Length);

            newMap = combined;
        }

        private byte[] decompress(byte[] a) {
            using(var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
                using(var decompressor = new DeflateStream(ms, CompressionMode.Decompress, CompressionLevel.Level9)) {
                    decompressor.Write(a, 0, a.Length);
                }
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }

        private byte[] compress(byte[] a, int level) {
            using(var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
                CompressionLevel compressionLevel = CompressionLevel.Default;

                switch (level) {
                case 0:
                    compressionLevel = CompressionLevel.Level0;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    compressionLevel = CompressionLevel.Level1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    compressionLevel = CompressionLevel.Level2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    compressionLevel = CompressionLevel.Level3;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    compressionLevel = CompressionLevel.Level4;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    compressionLevel = CompressionLevel.Level5;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    compressionLevel = CompressionLevel.Level6;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    compressionLevel = CompressionLevel.Level7;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    compressionLevel = CompressionLevel.Level8;
                    break;
                case 9:
                    compressionLevel = CompressionLevel.Level9;
                    break;
                }

                using(var compresssor = new DeflateStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, compressionLevel)) {
                    compresssor.Write(a, 0, a.Length);
                }
                return ms.ToArray();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is 79 coming from?  Is it suppose to be 61 + 28 = 89?

Comment: In previous versions the headerLength was indeed 61 bytes and the 'compressed content' started after this. It looked to me that in DE this has moved to 79 bytes

Comment: It looks like you have binary data with a header than may have ascii text.  So often the binary starts after a character like SOH.  You do not normally compress the header so you can read values without un-compressing.

Comment: when doing `var x = decompress(input); var ouput = compress(x);` the result for input==output is False.. Why? They use the same DeflateStream and CompressionLevel ?

Comment: Is the input compressed using .NET? "Deflate" is a technique and format, it's not guaranteed that every compressor compresses using the exact same setup. The output should be decompressible by deflate, as in compatible, but there's no guarantee that two different compression implementations will produce byte-for-byte the same output.

Comment: Looks like the other projects use compression level: 9 and windowBits: -15. If I'm correct this does make a difference. Any guidance on how to add WindowBits in c#?